# node.js unit testing mock dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node, proxyquire

I have a question on using proxyquire (or any other suggestions on how to test the following code)

If i have the following file to test:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (conf) {
    var exported = {};

    exported.getIssue = function (issueId, done) {
        ...

        ...
    };

    return exported;
};
```

How do i pass in the 'conf' variable while using proxyquire to mock 'path; var?

Is there any other way to do this if not using proxyquire?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to pass `conf` variable to the module/function required via proxyquire. Proxyquire has meaning to to do the same [CommonJs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) require stuff, but with the possibility of mocking and stubing some modules. So you should act the same.

```
var pathMock = {
   someMethod = function() {}  
};
var confMock = {
   someMethod = function() {}
};
spyOn(pathMock, 'someMethod').and.callThrough();
spyOn(confMock, 'someMethod').and.callThrough();

module   = proxyquire('../path/to/module', {
    path: pathMock
});

it('do some test', function(done) {
    module(conf).getIssue();
    expect(pathMock.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled;
    expect(confMock.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled;        
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! i will try this out and let you know if it worked!